# Hover in CSS not changing color property

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble with the following list. The problem is that when I hover on each of the elements, text color doesn't change.

[image: List]

My CSS code is supposed to change the color, but I don't know why it is not.

```
ul {
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    background: white;
    opacity: 0.8;
    position: absolute;
    top: 18%;
    left: 1.6%;
    width: 96.5%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #aeaeae;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #aeaeae;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #aeaeae;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 16.66685471%;
    padding-top: 0.8%;
    padding-bottom: 0.8%;
}

li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

li:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #FFD800;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #FFD800;
    color: white;
}
```

Jade file:

```
          ul
                li
                    a(href="/Catalogo") CATÁLOGO                    
                li
                    a(href="/Noticias") NOTICIAS
                li
                    a(href="/Proyectos") PROYECTOS
                li
                    a(href="/Eventos") EVENTOS
                li
                    a(href="/Acerca") ACERCA DE
                li
                    a(href="/Contacto") CONTACTO
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
li:hover a {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #FFD800;
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: If that doesn't work, it most likely means that you have some other css selector applied to your links with a higher specificity value. eg: nav.primary ul li a {color:black}